# Retrieve all videos added to all playlists by YouTube user

Tags: api, android-activity, youtube, feed, playlists

I've hit a wall with the way I would like to use the YouTube data API. I have a user account that is trying to act as an 'aggregator', by adding videos from various other channels into one of about 15 playlists, based on categories. My problem is, I can't get all these videos into a single feed, because they belong to various YouTube users. I'd like to get them all into a single list, so I could sort that master list by most recent and most popular, to populate different views in my web app.

**How can I get a list of all the videos that a user has added to any of their playlists?**

YouTube must track this kind of stuff, because if you go into the "Feed" section of any user's page at `http://www.youtube.com/' it gives you a stream of activity that includes videos added to playlists.

To be clear, I don't want to fetch a list of videos uploaded by just this user, so `http://gdata.../<user>/uploads` won't work. Since there are a number of different playlists, `http://gdata.../<user>/playlists` won't work either, because I would need to make about 15 requests each time I wanted to check for new videos.

There seems to be no way to retrieve a list of all videos that a user has added to all of their playlists. Can somebody think of a way to do this that I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for retrieving youtube links from playlist. It still need improvements.

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re
import os

more = 1
id_playlist = raw_input("Enter youtube playlist id: ")
number_of_iteration  = input("How much video links: ")
number = number_of_iteration / 50
number2 = number_of_iteration % 50
if (number2 != 0):
     number3 = number + 1
else:
     number3 = number
start_index = 1

while more <= number3:
     #reading youtube playlist page
     if (more != 1):
          start_index+=50

     str_start_index = str(start_index)
     req = urllib2.Request('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+ id_playlist     + '?v=2&&start-index=' + str_start_index + '&max-results=50')
     response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
     the_page = response.read()

     #writing page in .xml
     dat = open("web_content.xml","w")
     dat.write(the_page)
     dat.close()

     #searching page for links
     tree = et.parse('web_content.xml')
     all_links = tree.findall('*/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link[@rel="alternate"]')

     #writing links + attributes to .txt
     if (more == 1):
          till_links = 50
     else:
          till_links = start_index + 50

     str_till_links = str(till_links)
     dat2 = open ("links-"+ str_start_index +"to"+ str_till_links +".txt","w")
     for links in all_links:
          str1 = (str(links.attrib) + "\n")
          dat2.write(str1)     
     dat2.close()

     #getting only links
     f = open ("links-"+ str_start_index +"to"+ str_till_links +".txt","r")
     link_all = f.read()
     new_string = link_all.replace("{'href': '","")
     new_string2 = new_string.replace("', 'type': 'text/html', 'rel': 'alternate'}","")
     f.close()

     #writing links to .txt
     f = open ("links-"+ str_start_index +"to"+ str_till_links +".txt","w")
     f.write(new_string2)
     f.close()

     more+=1

os.remove('web_content.xml')
print "Finished!"
```